# Eclipse Error: 'AndroidDataBase' is missing required Java project: 'GoogleMaps'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]I am developing an app named "AndroidDataBase".
while am trying to compile in eclipse I am getting this error

```
Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741819   AndroidDataBase line 1  Android ADT Problem
```

and

```
 Project 'AndroidDataBase' is missing required Java project: 'GoogleMaps' .
```

Where GoogleMaps is another androidApp.

I have the **GoogleMap.java** in AndroidDataBase `"Src"` folder.

I have tried clean build ,restarting eclipse sort of things ,still no result

Why am i getting this error ,and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

I have added the GoogleMap.java
the issue is activity_googlemap its not getting identified 
although it is present in res/layout

Comment: Try to change your application API to GoogleMap Api from `Preference>select api level of Google API` @N.Nihar

Comment: still a newcomer can u plz elaborate ,
in eclipse ->windows-> preference i can t find anything like API to GoogleMap Api

but in properties-> Andriod ,I have selected Google APIS ,
no where i can find the GoogleMAPAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the "google-play-services_lib" project as a library project. You will find it in your_sdk_root_path/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Comment: Hey thanks dude,
although I have added that particular lib ,but I was getting the error 
All I did is went to that particular location and again added it .

Answer (score 0):

Set your Project Build Target to `Google API` Build. From right click on project and go to `Preference>Android tab>Select Target build of Google API`.

[image]

Comment: am using kepler
and in that i have selected Google APIs 2.2
should i change it to some higher version like 4.3 or something

Comment: Yes try to change and check .

Comment: no improvement 
just like we add jar files ,is there any way to add this googlemap

what confuses me more is whether eclipse is asking for googlemap.java or we need to give the complete app

when am checking the GoogleMap.java file i can show some errors indicting "***" can not be classified as a filed
where *** are diff params.

Comment: an android app which uses google play services to open the google map view

Comment: Then you must develop your project which is having build target as `Google API` as i have shown you in my answer.

Comment: What does your `AndroidDataBase` contains ?  Can you show code ?

Comment: what i am sure is that this is a build issue cz ,with the same code i can see the android app installed in a test phone 

there is a problem with just how to build it

Comment: Without any information i can not provide any solution. The one solution which i found suitable for your issue that i have already provided. Provide me more details or any kinda screenshot to understand your issue.

Comment: From your screen shot its showing that your application is not able to find the `activity_googlemap` layout file. Have you created the layout file in your `res/layout` folder ?

Comment: @N.Nihar Try to clean your project and build again .

Answer (score 0):

I Dint installed the "Google Play Service" present in the SDK Manager .
Once I did that ,all I need is to follow the solution of # Joan P.S(Stated above I have accepted the ans,thanks to him.).
After that I have to add the Google MAP project(import it to the current work space(another app )) in Properties->Java Build Path->Projects  .
That's how it got solved